# Consuming webservices with arrays c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap

[image: This is the SOAP Request]

[image: and this is the SOAP Response]

This is the Struct class I create

```
public struct Biller
{

    public string BillerTag { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string FirstField { get; set; }
    public string FirstFieldFormat { get; set; }
    public string FirstFieldWidth { get; set; }
    public string SecondField { get; set; }
    public string SecondFieldFormat { get; set; }
    public string SecondFieldWidth { get; set; }
    public string ServiceCharge { get; set; }


}
```

I am trying to use this code but it only shows 1 and only the last output

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Retrieves list of available BILLERS for collection as well as other information necessary for the transaction")]
    public Biller GetBillerList(string AccountID, string UserName, string Password)
    {

    ECPNBills.ECPNBillsPaymentService Client = new ECPNBills.ECPNBillsPaymentService();
    ECPNBills.BStruct Str = new ECPNBills.BStruct();


        Biller Bil = new Biller();

        Str = Client.GetBillerList(AccountID, UserName, Password);


        foreach (ECPNBills.BStruct cd in Client.GetBillerList(AccountID, UserName, Password))
        {
            Bil.BillerTag = cd.BillerTag;
            Bil.Description = cd.Description;
            Bil.FirstField = cd.FirstField;
            Bil.FirstFieldFormat = cd.FirstFieldFormat;
            Bil.FirstFieldWidth = cd.FirstFieldWidth;
            Bil.SecondField = cd.SecondField;
            Bil.SecondFieldFormat = cd.SecondFieldFormat;
            Bil.SecondFieldWidth = cd.SecondFieldWidth;
            Bil.ServiceCharge = cd.ServiceCharge;

        }

        return Bil;



    }
```

I am not sure what code to use in order to get all the items from BStruct.

I am also trying to consume webservice to webservice. Thank you in advance~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `return type` of your method to `List<Biller>`.

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Retrieves list of available BILLERS for collection as well as other information necessary for the transaction")]
public List<Biller> GetBillerList(string AccountID, string UserName, string Password)
{

    ECPNBills.ECPNBillsPaymentService Client = new ECPNBills.ECPNBillsPaymentService();
    ECPNBills.BStruct Str = new ECPNBills.BStruct();


    List<Biller> BilList = new List<Biller>();

    Str = Client.GetBillerList(AccountID, UserName, Password);


    foreach (ECPNBills.BStruct cd in Client.GetBillerList(AccountID, UserName, Password))
    {
        Biller Bil = new Biller();

        Bil.BillerTag = cd.BillerTag;
        Bil.Description = cd.Description;
        Bil.FirstField = cd.FirstField;
        Bil.FirstFieldFormat = cd.FirstFieldFormat;
        Bil.FirstFieldWidth = cd.FirstFieldWidth;
        Bil.SecondField = cd.SecondField;
        Bil.SecondFieldFormat = cd.SecondFieldFormat;
        Bil.SecondFieldWidth = cd.SecondFieldWidth;
        Bil.ServiceCharge = cd.ServiceCharge;

        BilList.Add(Bil);
    }

    return BilList;

}
```